# Help installing demo site

Tags: craft3

I'm trying to install the Craft demo site on my local dev environment but I'm getting stuck trying to install Composer.

This command from the instructions didn't work.

```
cd happylager.test
composer install
```

The I tried this command from the Composer website:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '93b54496392c062774670ac18b134c3b3a95e5a5e5c8f1a9f115f203b75bf9a129d5daa8ba6a13e2cc8a1da0806388a8') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

I tried both as-is and putting it after the path to my directory first like so:

```
cd /path to directory
```

Then the above command.

It did seem to install a file named composer.phar but I'm not sure this is it, and moreover I don't have a vendor subfolder.

Am I missing anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So If you still have everything on your machine, the thing going wrong here is the `composer install` bit. It looks like you have installed composer locally inside the folder [but not globally](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally). You have a file called `composer.phar` inside you happylager.test folder.

The way you have composer at the moment (locally), you cannot do `composer install` in your terminal you have to do `php composer.phar install` from within you happylager.test.

This should sort it for you and you will get the vendor folder from it. Then, simply follow the other steps to installing the demo. I strongly recommend you [install composer globally](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) though, it'll be easier for you in the future :)

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I installed composer globally first, then ran the install directive in the site folder.